# Jelly Script Execution using Http POST Request using Java

Tags: java, jira, jelly

I encoded the username and password and created the url to login to a JIRA application and execute a Jelly script, using Java. That does work. But the problem is, through this URL, iam able to login to JIRA and goto JellyRunner and paste my script in the textarea. But cannot execute it. Can you please tell me how to execute the JellyScript using URL.

Comment: I think your question does not match your subject line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Java Http Post method to post all data directly to the required page. I didnot use JellyScript since i got stuck. Sorry fr not giving complete details..:):)

Thanks.